# How to send x-www-form-urlencoded with axis?

Tags: javascript, redux, axios

here is the screen shot of working postman form type.

[image: PostMan Screen Shot]

As you can see I am posting x-www-form-urlencoded data back.

So I search google and found multiple posts about how to send this data back with axios.

In my login screen, I have something like this.

```
const handleLogin = values => {
    setLoading(true);
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('username', values.username);
    params.append('password', values.password);
    params.append('grant_type', 'password');
    dispatch(fetchToken(params))
      .then(res => {
        navigation.navigate('Home', {screen: 'HomePage'});
      })
  };
```

In my redux, I have something like this.

```
export function fetchToken(params) {
  return async dispatch => {
    function onSuccess(response) {
      tokenData = response.data.Token;
      dispatch({type: LOGGED_IN, payload: response.data});
      return response;
    }
    try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
            };
            console.log(params)
            const response = await axios.post('/token', params, config);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token_local', JSON.stringify(response.data));
            return onSuccess(response);
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Provided username and password is incorrect');
            throw Error(error);
        }
  };
}
```

The thing is that I always get into `catch error` here. Even the username and password are the same. What am I doing wrong

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: @Nick  Request failed with status code 500. But when I send with postman its working